# Найти все четверки точек, являющихся вершинами квадратов

Tags: c++

Задано множество точек на плоскости. Найти все четверки точек, являющихся вершинами квадратов. Найти квадрат, внутри которого лежит наибольшее количество точек множества. Необходимо решить эту задачу ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО с использованием структур.
http://ideone.com/6u4r4c
точки float
вот то что я сделал
первая проблема: больше пяти точек на вход не берет
вторая проблема: находит лишние струтурки из 4ех точек, некоторые искомые не определяет.

Comment: Вот лёгкий вариант: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/177687/6802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что написано - ужасно и не читаемо.
Сделать хотя бы так:

Структура, хранящую иноформацию о точке.

```
struct Point
{
  float x, y;
}
```

дальше нужна функция, вычисляющая расстояние между двумя точками

```
float distance( Point 1, Point 2 );
```

Затем функция, проверяющая, образуют ли 4 точки квадрат

```
bool IsSquare( Point1, Point2, Point3, Point 4 )
{
  const float d12 = distance(Point1, Point2);
  const float d23 = distance(Point2, Point3);
  /*и т.д.*/

  return d12 == d23 && d23 == d34 && /*и т.д.*/
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а вот еще вопрос, по сортировке, как сделать всевозможные квадраты пожалуйста? Тогда надо будет еще доделать всевозможные проверки? Плюс еще со второй частью задания что делать?

Comment: Достаточно считать/сравнивать квадраты расстояний, чтобы избежать ненужного вычисления корня.

Comment: алгоритмически это решение - просто жуть. И еще очень сомнительно выглядит присвоение константе значения, получаемого из функции (даже несмотря на constexpr)